# Missing Ado.Net Entity Data Model on Visual Studio 11

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

Missing "Ado.Net Entity Data Model" on Visual Studio 11, how can i install it?

Comment: Can you please tell how you come to know it is missing?

Comment: Do you mean Lightswitch? Because there's no other product with "Visual Studio" and "2011" in the name. You may mean Visual Studio 11 beta?

Answer (score 0):

It's right here - click `Add New Item` in Solution Explorer, in a suitable project:

[image]

What type of project did you want to add it to??

Comment: i know where it is, i cant see that. I have all other, but not "Ado.net entity data model"

Comment: @SinanChik: yes, and **what type of project** are you trying to add this to??

Comment: I create a new project as "Wcf Library Service" and i want to add new Item "Ado.net entity data model"

Comment: @SinanChik: if you create a new e.g. "Console Application" - can you see the ADO.NET Entity model there??

Comment: no i cant. I also installed entity framework from "NuGet Packages for solution" stil nothing

Comment: maybe I should re-install it?

Comment: it's fixed. I repaired visual studio 11 beta